# flashmessenger can`t show anything when page loading with ajax

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, flash-message

i have a form that it send data with ajax post metod. when i set flashmessenger in action method, it don`t show any messege (i have to refresh the page for see the messege)!

how i can manage the flashmessenger for recognition ajax load page??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flashmessenger  uses sessions, in order for it to work you need to physically reload the page. You have to create your own mechanism; Whenever you get the callback you can append lets say your response to the same element in which you would have displayed the flashmessanger message.

Comment: To clarify a little bit what I think is intended: the controller handling your AJAX request sends back a data structure which is received by the client (no page reload). Then your client-side scripting (probably javascript, but I don't wish to assume) parses that data structure and places the message into your page wherever you want it.